# How to customize Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I want to customize the calendar days in fullcalendar.

I want to change from

```
['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
```

to

```
[T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T6, CN]
```

Its my code:

```
let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    locale: 'vi',
    firstDay: '1',
    timeZone: 'Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh',
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    defaultView: 'month',
    headerToolbar: {
      start: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek',
      center: 'title',
      end: 'prev, next'
    },
    titleFormat: {
      month: 'long'
    },
    dayCellContent: function (info) {
      let number = document.createElement("a");
      number.classList.add("fc-daygrid-day-number");
      number.innerHTML = info.dayNumberText.replace('日', '');

      if (info.view.type === "dayGridMonth") {
        return {
          html: number.outerHTML
        };
      }

      return {
        domNodes: []
      };
    },
  });
```

I tried method dayNamesShort, but it's failed.

Comment: dayNamesShort is from version 3 of fullCalendar. Have a look at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-formatting and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayHeaderFormat instead. You probably need a custom formatting function.